# Prevent CAGradientLayer from Overlapping inside UIImageView on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, gradient, cagradientlayer

I am applying a gradient in my custom `UITableViewCell` using `Storyboards` inside my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and I wanted to prevent my application of `CAGradientLayer` gradient to overlap. How can I do this?

This is my current code I'm using to prevent it from overlapping but the gradient only applies to the latest `indexPath` loaded in `UITableView`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    VideoTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"VideoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!gradientLayer) {
        gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    }
    gradientLayer.frame = cell.backgroundImage.bounds;
    gradientLayer.colors =  @[(id)[UIColor blackColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
    [cell.backgroundImage.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];

    return cell;
}
```

My `cell.backgroundImage` is simply an `UIImageView` where I load an image and apply a gradient in it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer that's working. I just set my backgroundImage sublayers to nil before applying the gradient.

```
cell.backgroundImage.layer.sublayers = nil;
```